# Microsoft single sign on with React app - tie into NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am creating a new React web app and I'm using NodeJS on the backend.

I have been tasked with figuring out how to implement Microsoft single sign on in the app so users can sign in with their Microsoft credentials.

I have the application set up in the Azure portal. I have followed online tutorials and figured out how to implement it in the React portion using `@azure/msal-browser` and `@azure/msal-react`.  So I get the usual Microsoft sign in screen like this:

[image]

And I am able to sign in and see some account details.

### **Question:**

Now my question is, how do I also sign in to the Node/Express backend of my app at the same time?  We want to have actions where the user can click "send email" and it will automatically send an email from their Microsoft account.  For that to happen, we need to do that in the Node server where it needs to be logged in as the user.  From my initial research, it looks like the Microsoft Graph API will be used.

I should also add a couple resources I have used along the way.  I used this tutorial to create a working React app that utilizes the single sign on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customers/tutorial-single-page-app-react-sign-in-prepare-app

And then I used this tutorial to successfully create a Node app that signs in the user, but does not use that single sign-on prompt from above: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about this is that you have two code bases talking to each other. You have a React process running in the browser and interacting with the user. Your React process needs to call back to a NodeJS process running on the backend.

Microsoft provides a framework with the SPA templates (Angular and React front end, ASP.NET Core back end). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates

The .NET Core backend serves the SPA/JavaScript/React/Angular files and then waits around for calls from the front end.

You could examine what the .NET Core backend does and replace it with your Node.JS application.

I've written up how I authenticate SPAs with Azure AD in case it helps:
https://mindline.com/august-1-authenticating-enterprise-apps-in-2023/
https://mindline.com/august-15-authenticating-apps-in-2023-a-closer-look/